# Does Islam oppress women?

Tags: women

One of the most asked question about Islam is that, does Islam oppress women?

Comment: Well, it's a ridiculously broad and vague claim. What does is mean to oppress someone? Does it mean to take away their "rights"? What do their rights include? Does it mean placing restrictions on people? We all agree that there should be restrictions on people (e.g. murder should be illegal). So where do we draw the line? When it hurts other people? Wait, so are suicide and self harm alright then? And what in particular do they think is oppressive in Islam? Do they believe that women have less "rights" or more restrictions then men? The claim needs to be made clearer.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38341/17702) for references how women are in a significantly worse legal position than men in sharia.

Comment: I agree with Student to some extent. Oppressive from which point of view? There need to be criterions to evaluate. The current answer focuses mostly on clothing choices and only gives the Islamic view of the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Islam does not oppress women. Men and women are equal in Islam but they don't have the exact same rights as they are not exactly the same mentally or physically. It is haram to oppress anyone and it is not the teaching of Islam. Islam teaches us to always treat each other well no matter what race, age, gender, culture or religion we belong to.

Most people say Islam oppresses women because of the hijab when in fact most Muslim females want to wear the hijab as it is a sign of dignity and modesty. When a lady is asked to wear the hijab it is not to oppress her but it is for her protection. Allah has only made that which will harm us haram and that which will benefit us halal. Women in Islam are allowed to do many thing but the western world do not understand this. If a Muslim lady does not wear the hijab, it is a sin for her. If a Christian woman does not cover her head she is told to shave her head. Even the statues of Mary all have a hijab on.

World English Bible:
"For if a woman is not covered, let her also be shorn. But if it is shameful for a woman to be shorn or shaved, let her be covered."

Also, in most religions such as Sikhism, Islam and Christianity the females cover themselves up. If it is wrong for a female to cover up then why does the Queen cover herself? Why does she not wear revealing clothes? Because she knows it is inappropriate. Islam treats all women like the Queen; With respect.

Comment: @Zohal, Oops, this sentence of your answer could be the best brief answer as you accurately pointed out "but they don't have the exact same rights as they are not exactly the same mentally or physically.". You indeed mentioned a fantastic point.

Comment: @SEYYED___ALIالسید____علی Jazak Allah Khair :)

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 20 verse 123
[ Allah ] said, "Descend from Paradise - **all, [your descendants] being enemies to one another**. And if there should come to you guidance from Me - then whoever follows My guidance will neither go astray [in the world] nor suffer [in the Hereafter].

Chapter 49 verse 13
O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. **Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of yo**u. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted.

Chapter 4 verse 3
And if you fear that you will not deal justly with the orphan girls, then marry those that please you of [other] women, two or three or four. **But if you fear that you will not be just, then [marry only]** one or those your right hand possesses. That is more suitable that you may not incline [to injustice].

I think these verses should sum up your question.
1. A fact that we are enermies to one another.*We will never treat each other the same.*

2. The noble of us is the righteous.*So if you oppress women you are not noble*
3. If you can not be just to more than 1 wife marry only one. *Y*ou have to marry one women and not treat her like a prostitute.**

Chapter 23 verse 33
But let them who find not [the means for] marriage abstain [from sexual relations] until Allah enriches them from His bounty. And those who seek a contract [for eventual emancipation] from among whom your right hands possess - then make a contract with them if you know there is within them goodness and give them from the wealth of Allah which He has given you. And do not compel your slave girls to prostitution, if they desire chastity, to seek [thereby] the temporary interests of worldly life. And if someone should compel them, then indeed, Allah is [to them], after their compulsion, Forgiving and Merciful.