# Does Islam teach subjugation and inequality of women, or is that due to a wrong interpretation of the religion?

Tags: women

Not a Muslim here - in the West we often hear talk of (what we see as) horrible non-equal treatment of women by Muslim culture in the East. Is it common for women to be in any way subjugated (given orders and rules which men aren't subject to, or being forced to behave as a husband demands, etc) like we often hear about, is this as a result of wrong interpretations of Islam, or does the religion really teach these principles?

I mean no offense, I'm genuinely curious and open minded on the issue.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification; they are not intended for answering questions or debating controversial points.

Answer (score 2):

There's many questions on here that may be pertinent:

- women are [considered inferior in intellect](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/182/17702)
- they are [supposed to stay at home mostly](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/476/are-women-allowed-to-work-in-islam?rq=1)
- the husband can determine [where she lives, whether she can leave the house or take up a job, demand sex and she has to oblige](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/37305/17702) (see also [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38759/17702) for how the husband can enforce these); for his right to keep her from leaving the house and demanding sex, there are restricted circumstances where she can ignore his demands
- if she doesn't have a husband, these rights (apart from demanding sex; extramarital sex is forbidden in islam, unless it's with a female slave) fall to a male relative, this is referred to as "guardianship" and the guardian is the "wali"
- the wali's consent is required for a woman to marry (see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38271/17702) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36986/does-the-father-have-to-be-present-during-the-nikah)), a man can marry without the consent of anyone but his bride; the consent of the wali is not required in the hanafi school of law, which accounts for roughly 30% of the Muslim population
- a woman never inherits more than a man in the same position and usually inherits less (see the topic [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37419/is-the-fact-that-a-woman-inherits-only-half-the-amount-of-a-man-a-kind-of-injust) - someone heard that sometimes they do inherit more than a man in the same position, but no one could find any evidence of that)
- a husband can dissolve a marriage by simply saying so ([talaq](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/103/just-reciting-talak-thrice-commits-divorce)), a woman needs her husband's consent and give him the dower back, or she needs a court order to have a marriage dissolved (these are called [khula or faskh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25539/any-other-procedure-for-divorce-for-women-other-than-khula))
- women have to cover a lot more than men
- men can [marry four women simultaneously](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76/why-are-muslims-allowed-to-marry-up-to-four-women), women are restricted to one husband at a time
- [virgin women can be married off by their wali without their consent](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39155/17702) in some madhahib (schools of law)

Comment: @Viziionary the husband does have more authority but at the same time he has much more responsibility...just like a CEO has 3X more responsibility than a VP does. If you solely look into one side, it would seem terribly unbalanced. Additionally these are all what Islam has **allowed**, it doesn't mean that a husband should jump onto his wife like an eagle demanding sex, force her to stay home and not see her friends/family, not give her money to spend and enjoy. See this answer [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35201/what-does-being-an-obedient-wife-really-mean/37299#37299)

Comment: @Viziionary Islam only sets the ultimate boundaries and then enjoins men to show the greatest respect to their wives. If you look into law, similarly you would see that a father has to feed his family, provide for them, protect them etc. Never in the law you see that he should show them love, care, kindness. Law is one thing, what's recommended, revered, expected is totally something else

Comment: @Honey The point is that sharia gives men a lot of power over women, women almost zero power over men, and generally sets women up in a far inferior position compared to men; what you would prefer to happen within those boundaries tells us nothing about what the system incentivises. People have to be protected by enforcable rights, not wishful thinking, and women in Islam have very few enforcable rights over men compared to the other way around.

Comment: True, Sharia gives more power, they're more capable, but again more responsibility. Would you have your wife cook for you, because she MUST or because of her love? Should a husband be forced to take his family to restaurant or he must do it out of love? My point is, a wife must **love** his husband not follow command as if she's in the army and if she doesn't then she'll be decimated. If enforcing gets involved too much then women will become depressed. And believe me if you look around, you'll see a great number of depressed Muslim families/women. My way is almost 180 different than yours.

Comment: @Honey The question isn't "what would G.Bach like his relationship with his girlfriend/wife/partner(s) to be like", it's "does Islam subjugate women". As a system, Islam puts women at an extremely disadvantaged position, and I've listed some of the major points in which way it does so. "If enforcing gets involved too much then women will become depressed. And believe me if you look around, you'll see a great number of depressed Muslim families/women." This answer explains why, to a large degree.

Comment: By the way, after condemning your belief system for inequality and subjugation of women, I do respect that people commented back not angrily but peacefully. I recognize that your religion probably encourages many good things, it's just unfortunate that it promotes such an unequal, degrading, and subjugating environment for women, which I study cognitive science and neurology and I know Islam's claim that women are more forgetful than men making them not equal witnesses is an inaccurate claim not supported by science. Science is in favor of women having memory function of equal quality to men.

Comment: I would also point out that if you tell a person they're a certain way, and everyone around them believes that's how they are naturally, they will unconsciously take up those characteristics because they believe it, so if your society tells women they're mentally lesser, many of them will develop mentally to take on those traits, in other words, they believe they're not as smart or have poor memory, so they don't strive toward higher thinking, higher intelligence, and good memory. The brain is very dynamic, like a muscle, and your thinking trains it and defines its capabilities.

Comment: @Viziionary "Does lack of inequality and the environment of subjugation bother the women of Islam?" No idea whether research into that exists, and if it would be on-topic here.

Comment: @G.Bach which is why I asked in a comment, but I cant see you arent going to entertain that - thanks for the information you gave.

Comment: This answer reflects a rather narrow view and can mostly be discussed or even disproved to some extent.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Can you be specific? Apart from a right to be sustained, I'm not aware of any substantial gender-specific enforceable rights that women have over men. I see no reason to include exhortations and unenforceable recommendations because they are a hope, not a reliable means of protecting people's interests, and I also didn't include gender-unspecific rights ("people generally cannot kill people" includes "men generally cannot kill women" but is not specific to the men-women distinction) because they are independent of gender distinctions - this includes rights that work both ways.

Comment: @G.Bach what you are struggling to prove is not exactly an answer of the Question.

Comment: @Viziionary I was wondering if there's something missing from the answer that you'd like to see addressed?

Comment: Could the downvoters let me know what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: I did not down vote. I'm new here. but what you say provoked some people.

Comment: all what you said is true. what are the outcomes if all the humanity applied this is what you miss.

Comment: @Viziionary I have two sisters that I'm the Wali of . I love them and protect them and provide for them (one works by the way and is preparing for her masters degree). We are muslims and we apply all what is above. and yet I never heard my sister cry because I did not let her go to buy something from the store in a late time of a day.

Answer (score -1):

Yesterday I was listening to a programme on radio 4 where a British man was explaining how in Victorian London women were subjugated and told only to be mothers.

Auteur temps, autre moeurs (other times, other morals).

Personally, this to me sounded a little anachronistic;  I doubt that women at the time thought of themselves as being subjugated. Who would want to work as a drudge in one of those satanic mills? Likewise in my ancestral village in Bangladesh I wouldn't want my sister to work in the fields or in the bazaar. Neither of which is pleasant work.

The difference is that the world in the West, and now elsewhere, has changed a great deal between them and now.

In the Qu'ran 2:187 we are taught that:

> They [your wives] are your garments and you are a garment for them.

We are not taught to 'subjugate' or 'oppress' them.