# What is the role of a Muslim woman?

Tags: women, islamic-philosophy, men-women

What is the role of a Muslim woman?

My father says women is there to please men and reproduce nothing else.  Is that true?  Women has no role in society, no job, no influence in any matter, nothing.  Why is that?

Edit: And I also know that women are there to be a slave like working in house, cooking, taking care of sick, sewing, etc.  I am not asking the duties I am asking the role of a Muslim woman.

Comment: "[Does Islam teach subjugation and inequality of women, or is that due to a wrong interpretation of the religion?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38338/17702)" could be related.

Comment: Basically what you have learnt is a dangerous and bad view of women. The teachings of Islam might not sound modern these days, but women are no household nor birth giving nor child up bringing slaves. And those whom pretend this are using strange interpretations or weak ahadith as evidences. The whole relationship husband-wife is taken very seriously in the quran Allah always use the word "if you fear" to show off this caution.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Plz prep an answer and post it would be very helpfull to know  the right place of women

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role of a woman in society:

> The best of the qualities in a woman is stitching and weaving.
>   -Imam Ali AS

So the role of the woman in a society is just the same - Stitching​ and Weaving

**Stitching**: The woman in Islamic society maintains the balance in the society by stitching up the differences in a family (or community on a large scale) and binds it together. She binds the family together and keeps it from falling apart. Ruling from the corner of her house, she turns it into a home - a place where every men seeks solace, however strong he might be.

**Weaving**: Another responsibility shouldered by a woman is to weave the future of Islam. She is responsible for upbringing the child and instilling values and morals in the next generation, thus weaving the future of Islam.

So the woman models the society in a way no man can accomplish. She works behind the veils, strengthening the society silently.

A woman in Islam is in no way oppressed or ill treated. Although the gender roles in Islam differ for man and woman, there is no difference in their status. A woman in Islamic ​society plays a vital role in the society, and is treated no lesser than a man.

Comment: So you put Not going outside for work and staying home as a slave in good words MashaAllah praises

Comment: I am not saying a woman should not go out for work and stay at home. I mean to say you cannot devalue a woman who prefers to stay at home and treat her like a slave. OP suggests that stay at home woman has no social role to play apart from pleasing men and reproducing. Woman is significant part of the society working silently without asking for attention. You just can't categorise woman as working/not working and demean her existence.

Answer (score 0):

1. Completes half emaan of male. It's mutual half emaan completion. Prophet said marriage is half of emaan.
2. Can become sole owner of inherited wealth if there are no male inheritors.
3. Can lead a women only congregation.
4. Become scholars and clear doubts regarding Islam.
5. Source of care for sick children, husband, brother, father, mother.
6. Become tailor, teacher, nurse or Doctor to help fellow muslim women.
7. Giving bath to funerals of women.
8. Women can go out and work in hijab, if it's dire necessity.

Edit: women are a creation of Allah. Spritually equal to men.